# How to export a readable email from mutt

Tags: mutt

Sometimes I would like to export an email, in readable plain-text format, with headers stripped and the text readable, just like it's shown to me when I read it in mutt.  It must surely be possible?

Of course there is the s-key for saving the email as it is, but unfortunately in 2017 very few emails are easily readable without any processing, there are often several pages with irrelevant headers, and there are different forms of content-transfer-encoding making the content itself unreadable, extra noise due to the multipart/alternative encoding, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I, often, use Escape-S to decode-save the message to a file. After that, I can edit the file to remove headers, signatures or anything else.

Comment: Actually, I think that's Esc + `s` (lower case) with mutt's default key bindings. (Remember that mutt's key bindings are case sensitive!) You can also use `decode-copy` (Esc + `C`) to copy rather than save (which in mutt implies "move") the message.

Comment: The above comment is correct, esc+s, not esc+S - and also, the email will be deleted if doing esc+s, so esc+C seems better.  Except for that - perfect, just what I was looking for.  It does include a bit more header lines than the plain view, but not far too many anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new maildir

```
mkdir -p ~/mymails/{cur,new,tmp}
```

Start mutt with your mailbox

```
mutt -f /var/mail/root
```

Press `:` for command mode and set the mailbox format to maildir with this command

```
set mbox_type=Maildir
```

Select you mails and save all selected with the `;s` or `;e` key sequence and use `~/mymails/`as target. Now all mails are saved as single files in mymails/cur.

Comment: The second paragraph of the question specifically rules out using plain `s` (or `e` which is basically the same thing). Saving into a maildir doesn't change any of that.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer for another question :p